# Get user input after opening window

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim, ctrlp

How do I get user input (so that I can filter some items) after opening a new window (which has the items)? I wanted something similar to [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) or [CtrlSpace](https://github.com/vim-ctrlspace/vim-ctrlspace). I tried to look at their code, but failed to identify where they do it.

The way I am calling it is by creating a `command` that calls a function `foo` that opens the window and waits for an user input.

I have already tried some variations (code inside `foo`):

```
botright split NewWindow
let input = input('>> ')
```

and

```
botright split NewWindow
redraw!
let input = input('>> ')
```

The first one always get me the input before opening the new window. In both of them the `>>` part doesn't show up (neither does the input itself). How do they do this? With a bunch of `getchar` calls?

(using Neovim v0.2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It seems it was not that difficult (for some reason I was lost in the source code and couldn't see it). They basically get one char at a time and keep echoing the results.

From what I could see, [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) uses the following approach:

- redraw
- ask for character with `getchar()`
- concatenate the character with an accumulator string
- echo the string
- loop while you want

My vimscript now looks like this:

```
let str = ''
while s:some_stop_condition()
    redraw
    let c = getchar()
    let str = str . nr2char(c)
    echo str
endwhile
```